# Override Rejections to Edits on my Post

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, edit-override

I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18453404/198633) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18453348/198633). One of the users who read my answer felt that it would have been helpful if I included the output (from terminal) to the code I used in my answer:

> You should include the output of your examples, people reading this won't always have the possibility to try it out. :)

Since I did not have access to a terminal at the time, I asked the user to run my code on the terminal and edit the output thereof into my post:

> @flornquake: Normally, I would, but I'm not at a terminal at the moment. I'd appreciate it if you were and could, though

I had to walk away from my computer for a while, but eventually, I did see a suggested edit (it was however, already reviewed by the time I could weigh in). The edit does exactly what I asked and has been rejected (2-3) for reasons that I don't agree with (`This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post`).

Now, I would like to be able to overrule the decision and include the suggested edit into my post. I prefer this option, as the alternative is for me to copy-paste the suggested edit and manually splice it in, myself; which is less efficient.

Does anyone think this is a viable feature to add?

Comment: The edit-suggester should have left an edit comment "incorporating example output as requested by answerer" - without that, people think the edit is changing your meaning and will reject it. The comments on the post are not shown in the review, only the edit summary